# Get value of any json by defining a key pattern at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I want to extract values of any json which I do not know the structure of at compile time. So I am looking for something like that:

```cs
public class JsonExtractor
{
    public string GetValue(string pattern, string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.GetValue<string>(json, pattern);
    }
}
```

```cs
string pattern = ".data.value";
string json = "{\"request\": {\"method\": \"get\", \"key\": \"test\"}, \"code\": 0, \"type\": \"call\", \"data\": {\"value\": 14.0}}";

var jsonExtractor = new JsonExtractor();
var value = jsonExtractor.GetValue(pattern, json);
```

What's important here is the value of `pattern` and the value + structure of the `json` is not known at compile time, i just created these two variables for illustration. I want to get a specific value within any json at runtime.

Comment: Seems that you need to deserialize to a generic JObject and then use reflection to trasverse all structure searching for the pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SelectToken` and modify your pattern to be a JSONPath (which is just adding a "$" to the start).

```
string pattern = "$.data.value";
string json = "{\"request\": {\"method\": \"get\", \"key\": \"test\"}, \"code\": 0, \"type\": \"call\", \"data\": {\"value\": 14.0}}";
int data = JToken.Parse(json).SelectToken(pattern).Value<int>();
Console.WriteLine(data); // print "14"
```

Note that you can put `<string>` as the generic argument as well, even though the JSON value is a Number.

Comment: `SelectToken` is actually method coming from `JToken` which also has `Parse` method, so you can just use it without any need to detect if the root is json array or json object.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks.